# How to do this C# thing in VB?

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

```
td.Triggers.Add(New DailyTrigger{DaysInterval = 2})
```

^^^ this is C#.NET code.

how to do it in VB.NET? I'm particularly confused about curly braces part, because VB.NET doesn't seem to be liking it.

Comment: @user959631 I don't think that matters in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
td.Triggers.Add(New DailyTrigger() With { _
    Key .DaysInterval = 2 })
```

Comment: +1: You've gotta love VB. I can only imagine the design meeting where that was decided . . . "So, this automatic property initialisation that C# has, let do the same thing but add a completely unnecessary word to the syntax. Now what reserved word can we re-use and there by increase the general confusion in the world." Sorry for mini rant, but  I often wonder does VB actually stand for **V** er **B** osity

Comment: Note that in most cases, the `Key` keyword is not needed. It's only useful if you compare an anonymous value to another.

Answer (score 3):

To explain the curly braces, that's just a shortcut for the following:

```
DailyTrigger dt = new DailyTrigger();
dt.DaysInterval = 2;
td.Triggers.Add(dt);
```

So, the equivalent in VB would simply be:

```
Dim dt As DailyTrigger = new DailyTrigger()
dt.DaysInterval = 2
td.Triggers.Add(dt)
```

Or, to use the similar `With` shortcut:

```
td.Triggers.Add(New DailyTrigger() With { .DaysInterval = 2 })
```

But that shortcut syntax was not added to VB.NET until a later version (part of LINQ, I believe), so if you aren't using the latest version of .NET, that may not work.